# Transfer Ether from main account to different accounts

Tags: blockchain, ether, wallets, exchanges

I want to purchase some Ether from currency exchange websites and then transfer it using an API call to different accounts. Do I need a blockchain for such scenario ?

Also, can we create wallets from any websites and receive Ether from any currency exchange website ?

Update: I am creating a game where users will be rewarded with some Ether once they complete a challenge. Before we can reward users , we will have to purchase some Ether from currency exchange like Kraken(Don't want to mine it). Once we purchase it, we want to keep it in our wallet(base account) and then transfer to different Ether accounts/wallets provided by users.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write API's for transferring ethers(or interacting with blockchain), you need to download the blockchain and ideally, you should.

> Also, can we create wallets from any websites and receive Ether from
>   any currency exchange website?

Yes, you can use any wallet of your choice and transfer ethers from any cryptocurrency exchange to your wallet. The most popular one is Ethereum-Wallet. You could also use third-party like MyEtherWallet or Metamask(Chrome Plugin) to create an account and transfer ethers form exchange to that address. Don't lose or share private key of your account. The loss of the private key will result in permanent loss of funds.

Comment: What is meant by downloading blockchain ? If I purchase some real Ether from crypto-currency exchange how will I link it with my blockchain ? Can I do it without blockchain ? Purchase and just transfer to multiple accounts using already given API's ?

Comment: You can definitely buy ethers without having a blockchain. If you want your ethers to remain at your exchange address .it's fine. But if you want to use Ethereum-Wallet to store your ethers, in this case, you need to download the complete chain. If you do not want to download the chain and want to move fund out of exchange you could use third-party wallets like MEW. I really do not understand, what do you mean by `already given api's`? It will be really nice if you could edit your question and let us know what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: I have updated my answer. I am unable to get API(from MyEtherWallet) where I can transfer Ether from my wallet to any wallet address. https://www.myetherwallet.com/#send-transaction.

Also can I have your contact info please(mob. no.) ? I just need 5 mins max to discuss it. I am new to this concept.

Comment: Hi Vivek, Are you sure MEW provides such api to release funds from accounts. I check a list at https://www.myetherapi.com/ but couldn't find any for `sendTransaction`.  This is obvious as MEW is a wallet, not a merchant platform. You can try https://www.coinpayments.net. Also, my contatc no is +91-9990053172. You can call anytime.

Comment: Oh... I must have viewed an incorrect documentation. What I need is simply transfer some Ether from one wallet to other using API. I know MEW has a UI interface for doing so but I need an API for that.  I will check coinpayments as they are a merchant platform.